# How to merge two csv files?

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files like this

```
"id","h1","h2","h3", ...
"1","blah","blahla"
"4","bleh","bleah"
```

I'd like to merge the two files so that if there's the same id in both files, the values of the row should come from the second file. If they have different ids, then the merged file should contain both rows.

---

Some values have comas

```
"54","34,2,3","blah"
```

Comment: Are the files sorted by id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = {}

a=open('a.csv')
for line in a:
    (id, rest) = line.split(',', 1)
    res[id] = rest
a.close()

b=open('b.csv')
for line in b:
    (id, rest) = line.split(',', 1)
    res[id] = rest
b.close()

c=open('c.csv', 'w')
for id, rest in res.items():
    f.write(id+","+rest)
f.close()
```

Basically you're using the first column of each line as key in the dictionary `res`. Because b.csv is the second file, keys that already existed in the first file (a.csv) will be overwritten. Finally you merge `key` and `rest` together again in the output file c.csv.

Also the header row will be taken from the second file, but these should not differ anyway I guess.

**Edit:** A slightly different solution that merges an arbitrary number of files and outputs rows in order:

```
res = {}
files_to_merge = ['a.csv', 'b.csv']
for filename in files_to_merge:
    f=open(filename)
    for line in f:
        (id, rest) = line.split(',', 1)
        if rest[-1] != '\n': #last line may be missing a newline
            rest = rest + '\n'
        res[id] = rest
    f.close()

f=open('c.csv', 'w')
f.write("\"id\","+res["\"id\""])
del res["\"id\""]
for id, rest in sorted(res.iteritems()):
    f.write(id+","+rest)
f.close()
```

Comment: What happens if the id is different in each file?  As the op stated, both should show up in the csv you're writing.

Comment: OP said, that if an id is in both files, then the row from the second file should be chosen. If an id exists in only one of both documents, then it should be in the result as well. That's what this script should be doing.

Comment: I see it now.  Nice use of dicts!

Comment: Note that the reason people tend to prefer the `csv` module to splitting on `','` is that this assumes that there's no quoted comma to cause trouble.  Here, where it seems the IDs are integers, that's probably not a problem, but if the ids were names, e.g. `"Smith, John"`, it wouldn't work.  The `csv` solutions work in both cases.

Comment: @DSM thanks for pointing that out. Actually, some of the values in the row have comas in them, but not in the id column, so should still work?

Comment: Indeed, it's a good point, but nevertheless this solution should still work for you, if you can guarantee, that the **first** column (=id) will never have comma in it.

Comment: another remark is that first need to print the header row separately, because dict returns an unordered set

Answer (score 2):

Keeping key order, and maintaining the last row based on `id`, you can do something like:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

incsv = [csv.DictReader(open(fname)) for fname in ('/home/jon/tmp/test1.txt', '/home/jon/tmp/test2.txt')]
rows = OrderedDict((row['id'], row) for row in chain.from_iterable(incsv))
for row in rows.itervalues(): # write out to new file or whatever here instead
    print row
```

Comment: this prints a dictionary, not a csv file

Comment: @siamii Indeed... I left the output of the "merged file" up to you as you didn't explicitly state that you wanted a CSV file output - just a "merged file". And - it's not that difficult from the code shown to look at the `csv` module and figure out what `DictReader`'s opposite number is...

Answer (score 1):

### Python3

```
import csv

with open("a.csv") as a:
    fields = next(a)
    D = {k: v for k,*v in csv.reader(a)}

with open("b.csv") as b:
    next(b)
    D.update({k: v for k,*v in csv.reader(b)})

with open("c.csv", "w") as c:
    c.write(fields)
    csv.writer(c, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL).writerows([k]+v for k,v in D.items())
```

Comment: I think you need `newline=''` for Python 3.